# Upstart 1.6 Doubts about performance

Tags: upstart

With Upstart 1.6, I have a couple of questions:

1. What does it mean it is able to "boot without initramfs". Does it mean it will boot faster without loading an image to RAM (Or doing it with an alternative way).
2. How will processes running in init be managed differently compared to previous versions of Upstart?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. See the SpamapS's answer in your another question in [With Upstart what does it mean in terms of performance to have a "initramfs-less boot support"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/222613/with-upstart-what-does-it-mean-in-terms-of-performance-to-have-a-initramfs-less)
2. They are not managed any differently. 1.6 does not change any part of the process handling. It does add stateful re-exec, but it is invisible to the processes.